# Error trapping ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

If you are writing a ModelBuilder model with a lot of geospatial data in it, and if one of the datasets fails or doesn't work, does the model stop and thus not produce any output?

Comment: correct. you can avoid this problem in python using e.g. try/catch loop

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if ModelBuilder finds a corrupt file or if any of the processing fails at any point, the model will stop and you will receive an error message.  You may be able to handle, or bypass, some of these errors within ModelBuilder.  ModelBuilder has rudimentary error handling capabilities using Python code block in the Calculate Value tool. There is a [very good ESRI blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/) on the subject that will walk you through various scenarios.  However, this is all much easier with a pure Python approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a model you created using Model Builder and one of your datasets fails for whatever reason, the tool will stop running.  However, if you are using an iterator, any data created as an output prior to the iteration with the failure should still exist.

For example, if you are using Model Builder to iterate through 100 rasters and perform some action on them, and your tool fails on raster number 100, you should still have the output from the first 99 files.  You should be able to see results of your model in the window that pops up while its running (for example, which file caused it to fail).  You would only need to run your tool again on the 100th file that was not run correctly the first time, not on all of the files.

Comment: I can see that for raster side but what about the vector side ?

Comment: It should be the same for raster or vector data.